# Set USB HD to Better Performance on Windows Server Core

Tags: windows, performance, hyper-v-server-2012, windows-server-core

I have a USB hard drive plugged into a server running Windows Hyper-V-server, which in many respects is like Windows Server Core in that it has no GUI and no way to get to device manager. On a normal Windows PC the default for USB drives is for quick removal, and I'm *assuming* this is the same on the server. If it were plugged into my PC then I could use device manager to change this policy to "Better performance".

My question is this: on Windows Hyper-V-server or Windows Server-Core, how can I set a USB HD to "Better Performance" instead of "Quick removal"? (I already know how to safely eject using a third party tool.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `regedit.exe` and navigate to:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR

find the USB device you want to change and navigate down through

> ..Device Parameters\Classpnp

There should be a DWORD value `UserRemovalPolicy` a `2` represents `Better Performance` and a `3` stands for `Quick Removal`.

On my machine a reboot is required, but in my case the Server OS is installed on the USB disk in question, so I'm not sure about that. Also on my machine `2` was the default which makes sense for servers, so you may not have to change anything.

Comment: Excllent, thank you @peter.

On my server `..Device Parameters\Classpnp` didn't exist. Having looked at it on my Windows 8 pc it looks like `Classpnp\UserRemovalPolicy` is only created when the policy is changed. So, if anyone else is reading this and you don't see `Classpnp` under `Device Parameters` then you will need to create a new key `Classpnp` and under that add the DWORD `UserRemovalPolicy` with the value `2`. I think a reboot will always be required, but I can live with that.